# cmake and default compilers

Tags: c++, gcc, g++, cmake

I have recently updated my OS X to Mountain Lion. Unfortunately FreeBSD switched to a compiler suite (llvm/clang) that does not support OpenMP, that I need, and Apple set that suite as the default compilation tools.

Fortunately OS X 10.8 includes an old gcc 4.2 compiler, that can still be used for some legacy code.

I build the programs using cmake (v2.8). In order to use the gcc compiler, I first tried to set two variables in the CMakeLists.txt script. More specifically, I set `CMAKE_C_COMPILER` and `CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER`. However, setting these two variables had no effect: cmake kept using the llvm compiler not supporting OpenMP.

Then I tried to set two environment variables, `CC` and `CXX` (in the .profile/.bashrc script), pointing to the same compilers used for the CMake variables. By using these two variables, I am able to compile my source code.

My question is: what's the point of the two CMake variables (CMAKE_..._COMPILER)? How am I supposed to use them?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

These variables can indeed be used, but they must be set **before** the compiler is automatically detected. You usually do so using either the command line or with a cache-initialization script:

```
# by setting CC anc CXX
CC=gcc-4.2 CXX=g++-4.2 cmake ...

# by passing the definitions of CMAKE_{C,CXX}_COMPILER to cmake directly
cmake -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER:FILEPATH=`which gcc-4.2` -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER:FILEPATH=`which g++-4.2` ...

# by passing a cache-initialization script
cmake -C init_cache.cmake
```

Where the file `init_cache.cmake` contains things like

```
set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER CACHE FILEPATH /usr/bin/gcc-4.2)
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER CACHE FILEPATH /usr/bin/g++-4.2)
```

Comment: I'd just add that the first option (env. vars `CC` and `CXX`) is generally viewed as the preferred way of selecting compilers for CMake. **And** that it must be done in a fresh binary tree. Once CMake detects compilers, they're baked into its cache (and most likely `CMakeTemp` as well).

Comment: You're very welcome. Note that the first method (i.e. setting `CC` and `CXX`) is considered to be the preferred one by the CMake developers. I found the last method to be very useful when working with automated builds.

Comment: @Angew true. If you change these variables *in the cache* after creating the build tree, CMake will notice and re-configure from scratch.